# Make the glossary title upper case in header

Tags: header-footer, glossaries, fancyhdr, capitalization, report

I'm using the `report` class with twoside parameter. I'm using `fancyhdr` to configure the headers/footer.

I'm using the `glossaries` package to generate a glossary. The glossary is the only chapter in my document for which the title does not appear in upper case in the header.

Here is how I print the glossary:

```
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}

\printglossary
```

I'm using exactly the same code for the index and the title just works great.

Is there a way I can force the title to upper case in the header ?

EDIT: I created a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{test}{
  name=test,
  description={test}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
Ceci est un \gls{test}. 

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\usepackage[ucmark=true]{glossaries}`; the default is false. Alternatively issue `\glsucmarktrue` after loading the package.

Comment: I tried both right now, but neither of them change anything.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry for that. I added one to the post.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht: It could be that you need to update your packages. [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) on CTAN is listed as `3.03`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ucmark` package option:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
}

\usepackage[ucmark]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{test}{
  name=test,
  description={test}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
Ceci est un \gls{test}. 

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to directly redefine `\glossarymark` (in fact, this is what the `ucmark` option does):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\glossarymark}[1]{%
   \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I have "LaTeX Error: Unknown option `ucmark' for package `glossaries'", when I do that. Apparently, my glossaries package is outdated, will try to update it.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht yes, you need to update the package.

Comment: There are no more recent versions of glossaries on my system, so I emulated ucmark with renewing glossarymark. Thanks.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht you can get the most recent version from CTAN: [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries). As for redefining `\glossarymark`, I've added this option to my answer.